# Get columns from create_engine (postgresql)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

In my function I'm having

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
query = "SELECT * from users"
eng = create_engine(f'postgresql://{self.user}:{self.pwd}@{self.host}:{self.port}/{self.db}',execution_options={"stream_results":True})
con = eng.connect()
ex = con.execute(query)
df = pd.DataFrame(ex.fetchall())
df.columns = <lost>
```

how do I get the column-names from the `users` tables?

I have tried

```py
col = [desc[0] for desc in con.cursor().description]

#'Connection' object has no attribute 'cursor'

col = [name for name in con.cursor().Columns]
#'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' object has no attribute 'Columns'

col = [desc[0] for desc in eng.raw_connection().cursor().description.name]
# 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

based on the documentation [(cursor)](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.cursor) and [(Columns)](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.Column), but I think it is for pure psycopg2-connections. I cannot find it when used together with `sqlalchemy`

Comment: Since you're creating a DataFrame why not just use [pd.read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) ?

Comment: Since I dont have enough memory. `read_sql` have some serious issues when reading from e.g postgresSQL, even if `chunk_size` is specified

Comment: One way would be `rows = ex.fetchall()` then `col_names = rows[0]._fields`